# ParseException line cannot recognize input near '(' 'select' 'from' in joinSource

Tags: hive

I am trying to execute a query in hive and getting the error. I check over and over again but I cannot see any problem.

```
select 
a.phone_no,
a.app_name
from 
(select * from (select app_name,phone_no from lc_app_flag) ) a 
inner join 
(select * from (select phone_no,city_id_day,city_id_night,lat_day,lng_day,lat_night,lat_night from TW_FEATS_FIN_LCEXT01 where month_id='202205'  ) b where city_id_day='440100' or city_id_night='440100') c
on a.phone_no=c.phone_no
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed aliasing first innermost subquery. Correct SQL below -

```
select 
a.phone_no,
a.app_name
from 
(select * from (select app_name,phone_no from lc_app_flag) subq)  a --inner subquery as subq
inner join 
(select * from (select phone_no,city_id_day,city_id_night,lat_day,lng_day,lat_night,lat_night from TW_FEATS_FIN_LCEXT01 where month_id='202205'  ) b where city_id_day='440100' or city_id_night='440100') c
on a.phone_no=c.phone_no
```

Comment: oh， it doesn't work